# Node.js server not receiving upload request from angular site (using express-fileupload)

Tags: node.js, angular

I created a node.js web server that uses express-fileupload to receive a multipart/form-data upload, I cannot seem to get it right tough, here is my node part:

```
app.post('/uploadImage', function(req, res) {
console.log("uploadImage");
if (!req.files)
  return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

let uploadedFile = req.files.uploadedFile;

if(uploadedFile.mimetype.indexOf("image") > -1){
  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  uploadedFile.mv('./' + uploadedFile.name, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.sendStatus(500);

    res.json({result: "uploaded successfully!"});
    });
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
      <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img [src]="imgPath" class="img-responsive text-center" style="max-height: 75px"/>
          <input id="artUpload" type="file" class="btn-success text-center" name="uploaded_file.png"/>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and the typescript:

```
upload(){
let formData: FormData;
formData = new FormData(<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('uploadForm'));
let input: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('artUpload');
formData.set('uploadedimage', input.files.item(0),'uploadedimage.png');
server.sendForm(formdata);
}
```

The object passed to the server.sendForm method does not contain any files. The 'uploadedimage' key does also not show when it is logged in the console. This works if you use the stock html given on the express-fileupload npm site.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `express-fileupload`, I used directly `connect-busboy`:

**Frontend side**

`html template`

```html
<div>

  <form>

    <div class="form-group"><label for="upload">Fichier</label>
      <input id="upload" type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)"/>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

`component.ts`

```
changeListener($event): void {
    console.log('change listener');
    this.readThis($event.target);
  }

readThis(inputValue: any): void {

    const file: File = inputValue.files[0];
    this.filename = file.name;
    const fileExtension: string = this.filename.substr((this.filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)); // read the extension of the file
    this.appService.deployement(file);
  }
```

`service angular`

```js
deployement(file: File) {
    console.log('service angular');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/*');
    // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(URL_API_REST + 'upload', formData, headers)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json())
  }
```

**Server side**

`app.js`

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
...
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    console.log("upload");

    if (req.method === 'GET')
        return res.json({'status': 'GET not allowed'});

    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
    });

});
```

*Only make sure that you created a directory `files` in your app's home of the server, otherwise you will get an error when running the server.*